# How to copy all files in a folder on s3 using Fog in Ruby

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, fog

How do I copy all the files present in an s3 directory(same prefix) to another directory in the same bucket using fog?

For eg: Copy all files with prefix `<bucket>/foo/` to `<bucket>/bar/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a direct way to do that per se, and that instead you would need to iterate over the appropriate files to do the move. I think it would look something like this:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'fog'

# create a connection
connection = Fog::Storage.new({
  provider:             'AWS',
  aws_access_key_id:     YOUR_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
  aws_secret_access_key: YOUR_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
})

directory = connection.directories.get(BUCKET, prefix: '/foo/')

directory.files.each do |file|
  file.copy(BUCKET, "/bar/#{file.key.split('/').last}")
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Just instead of {file.key}, I used {file.key.split("/")[-1]} to correctly copy the exact file name.

Comment: Oh yeah, that makes total sense. Glad that helped. I'll update my answer to reflect this in case anyone else comes across this.